# how can we configure to pull npm packages from Jfrog artifacts for yaml based azure CI Pipeline?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I want to configure an Azure DevOps yaml CI pipeline for a front-end angular app, where i need to get all the npm packages explicitly from Jfrog Artifacts.

Can anyone please help me, how can i define endpoints to pull the jfrog npm packages as npm install.

I have tried to follow the below link but unable to get something meaningful.

> https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Pipeline+Example%3A+Hello+World

I have written the below code-

```
pool:
  name: 'myProject'

variables:
  BuildConfiguration: 'Release'

trigger:
- master

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install from jfrog artifactory'
  inputs:
    workingDir: Web
    verbose: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish artifacts: drop'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> configure to pull npm packages from Jfrog artifacts

Artifactory provides tight integration Azure DevOps through the [JFrog Artifactory Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension).

The `Artifactory Generic Download task` supports downloading your build dependencies from Artifactory to the build agent. The task triggers the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) to perform the download. The downloaded dependencies are defined using [File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs) and can be also configured to capture the build-info. It will store the downloaded files as dependencies in the build-info.

The extension adds the following tasks: Artifactory NuGet, Artifactory .NET Core, Artifactory Maven, Artifactory Gradle, Artifactory npm and Artifactory Go to support full build integration with Artifactory. All tasks allow resolving dependencies and deploying artifacts from and to Artifactory.

This [document](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Azure%20DevOps%20and%20TFS%20Artifactory%20Extension) will give you guidelines.

Comment: Lin....  Is there any possibility without integration of extension, can i pull all the the dependency from jfrog artifacts using some custom configuration or using .npmrc file for my UI project ?

Comment: All I know is through extension.